# Plotting NDSolve solution does not cover all the integration domain

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have a set of four coupled Ordinary Differential Equations and I would like to solve it numerically with `NDSolve`. The explicit forms of these equations are not very instructive here because they are complicated (for your information, it is the field equations of a modified theory of gravity with spherical symmetry).

EDIT : Link to download my notebook : [Notebook](http://www.mediafire.com/file/39ycef2a8fcl5u8/bigravity_stars_ndsolve.nb/file)

For my purpose here, I have an initial condition at a large radius and I want to integrate backward in $r$ until $R=1.0$. Therefore, after defining my equations and my conditions, I use the following instruction

```
sm = NDSolve[{eqn, eqY, eqU, eqp, n[rmax] == nmax, Y[rmax] == Ymax,U[rmax] == Umax,p[rmax]==0.0}, {n, Y, U, p}, {r, 1.0, rmax},AccuracyGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 10]
```

The integration seems successful since I have the following output without any errors

[image: Output of NDSolve without any errors]

But then, when I want to plot the solution (for example the function $N(r)$) with the command :

```
plotm = Plot[Evaluate[n[r] /. sm], {r, 1.0, rmax},PlotTheme -> "Scientific", ImageSize -> Large]
```

there is nothing under $r\approx 5$ even though the integration domain is `[1.0,rmax]`. See on this picture what I get

[image: Plot]

I have the same problem by plotting $Y(r)$ or $U(r)$ (but their plots stop at different radius). It looks like the integrator failed to reach $R=1$ but usually, it prints an error message in this case.  Even more weird, if I ask directly for the numerical value of $N(r)$, it seems to work perfectly. For example, with the instruction :

```
For[i = 0, i <= 100, i++, Block[{r}, r = 1 + 49.0/100 i; Print[r, "\t", n[r] /. sm]]]
```

I get the following result

[image: Numerical values]

I have tried to change the vertical axis range on the plot : it changes nothing. The plot stops below some value of r greater than 1.
I am not an expert with these features of Mathematica so may be I have forgotten something obvious but actually I do not see what it is.

Any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: No full code,no idea,there will be no answer.

Comment: You really want all my code ? It is very long. And all the beginning is about deriving the field equations, there is no problem about this part...

Comment: Without code other people can run, you won't be able to get any help.

Comment: Ok but is it possible to put the .nb file somewhere directly ? Because I think it is more covenient than to copy-paste everything on a post.

Comment: I edited my post to add a link to download my notebook.